# Design a Class Diagram

Tags: arraylist

Hi I have  a class which contains an ArrayList as an attribute and I have initialized it like this:
     List arrayList = new ArrayList();

and I want to design a class diagram for my class, but I don't know how to refer to the type of the arrayList, should I write (  arrayList : **ArrayList**  )  or I have to write
 (  arrayList : **List**  )  ??

Answer (score 0):

Since you've declared the variable as being of type List, the fact that it is backed by an ArrayList is just an implementation detail. You should be able to replace it by any other kind of list object and get the same functionality.

If I were you, I wouldn't name the List "arrayList". If you called it "theList" or something of that nature then it would become a little more obvious that the fact that it's an ArrayList isn't important from a class diagram point of view.

Comment: so if I changed the name to for example to myList, in the class diagram just referring to the List is enough??

Comment: Class diagrams are supposed to capture names and relationships. They help you to see the overall structure of a program and how the different components interact. If you had a sorting algorithm, and you called it sort(), should the class diagram be aware of what kind of sort it is? Should it contain some extra information telling the reader that it's a Quick Sort or a Bucket Sort? Not really, because it's not important from that perspective. All the class diagram needs to communicate is that this particular class has a sorting method.